# Responsive div based on image width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-position, responsive

I'm having some images of a laptop and a tablet. Above the laptop there is a div, this div sould always be de width of the laptop. It all shows nice, until i scale my windows to something smaller.

I would like to have, when i make my screen smaller or when i look at it from a movile device that its scales properly.

This is what i have when full width:
[image]

and when i acces it on smaller devices i got this bad thing:
[image]

HTML block:

```
            <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="rain">
                 /* raindrops here */
            </div>

            {{-- RAIN DROPS(IMAGES) --}}
            <div class="parent">
                <img src="{{ url('img/header/laptop.svg') }}" class="laptop">
                <img src="{{ url('img/header/tablet.svg') }}" class="tablet">
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .rain {
    position: relative;
    width: 536px;
    height: 329px;
    opacity: 0.52;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(107, 233, 228, 0), #6be9e4);
    left: 120px;
    top: -60px;
}

    .parent {
        position: relative;
        top: 50;
        left: 0;
    }
    .laptop {
        position: absolute;
        left: -45px;
        top: -145px;
    }
    .tablet {
        position: absolute;
        left: -45px;
        top: 15px;
    }
```

How can i make this correct, tips, suggestions?

https://jsfiddle.net/fa8711au/1/

Comment: Put this in a jsFiddle will you.

Comment: Ramon could you share all of your code? This is not enough to go by.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fa8711au/1/

thare you go

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Main rectangle */

.rain {
  position: relative;
  width: 536px;
  height: 329px;
  opacity: 0.52;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(107, 233, 228, 0), #6be9e4);
  left: 120px;
  top: -60px;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(91deg, #7602f0, #00c7ff);
  min-height: 610px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 50;
  left: 0;
}

.laptop {
  position: absolute;
  left: -45px;
  top: -145px;
}

.tablet {
  position: absolute;
  left: -45px;
  top: 15px;
}



@media screen and (max-width:767px)
{
  .rain
  {
    width:100%;
    left:0px;
  }
  .laptop
  {
    max-width:100%;
  }
  .tablet
  {
    max-width:50%;
  }
  .parent
  {
    max-width:320px;
  }
  .tablet
  {
   top: -70px; 
  }
  
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="rain">
      <div class="Oval Orval-Main color-1"></div>
      <div class="Oval-Copy Orval-Main color-1"></div>
      <div class="Oval-2 Orval-Main color-2"></div>
      <div class="Oval-3 Orval-Main color-1"></div>
      <div class="Oval-4 Orval-Main color-1"></div>
      <div class="Oval-5 Orval-Main color-1"></div>
      <div class="Oval-6 Orval-Main color-2"></div>
      <div class="Oval-7 Orval-Main color-7"></div>
      <div class="Oval-8 Orval-Main color-1"></div>
      <div class="Oval-9 Orval-Main color-9"></div>

      <div class="Rectangle Rectangle-main"></div>
      <div class="Rectangle-Copy Rectangle-main"></div>
      <div class="Rectangle-2 Rectangle-main"></div>
      <div class="Rectangle-3 Rectangle-main"></div>
      <div class="Rectangle-4 Rectangle-main"></div>
      <div class="Rectangle-5 Rectangle-main"></div>
      <div class="Rectangle-6 Rectangle-main"></div>
      <div class="Rectangle-8 Rectangle-main"></div>
      <div class="Rectangle-9 Rectangle-main"></div>
      <div class="Rectangle-10 Rectangle-main"></div>
      <div class="Rectangle-11 Rectangle-main"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="parent">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/kAKVOn/laptop.png" class="laptop">
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iyOqOn/tablet.png" class="tablet">
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```